# Fungible asset max supply?

Tags: solana, metaplex, tokenmetadataprogram

Does anyone know how I can add a max supply to a Metaplex fungible asset ?

```
  const metadata = await Metadata.getPDA(mint.publicKey);
  
  const createMetadataTx = new CreateMetadataV2(
    { feePayer: mint_authority.publicKey },
    {
      metadata,
      metadataData: new DataV2({
        uri :'https://xxxx-88-81-106-161.ngrok.io/sample-uri',
        name: 'ttt',
        symbol: 'ttt',
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 100,
        creators: null,
        collection: null,
        uses: null,
        tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible
      }),
      updateAuthority: mint_authority.publicKey,
      mint: mint.publicKey,
      mintAuthority: mint_authority.publicKey,
    },
  );

  const sig = await connection.sendTransaction(createMetadataTx, [mint_authority],{
    skipPreflight: false,
  } )
    
  const txRpcResponse = await connection.confirmTransaction(sig)
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the current Metadata Struct, there is no such field as max supply  you can look more into the SPL token program it contains a field called supply to know more about it you can look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGQsS.png) or checkout the Solana Program Library Repo